# PHP - Como deixar um Array no mesmo nível?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
"resposta": [
        [
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing"
            }
        ],
        {
            "1": {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            "2": {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ",
                "valor": "https://google.com"
            },
            "3": {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            "4": {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ",
                "valor": "https://newton.ag"
            },
            "5": {
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            }
        },
        {
            "5": {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            "6": {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ",
                "valor": "https://google.com"
            },
            "7": {
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            }
        },
        {
            "8": {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            }
        },
        {
            "9": {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            "10": {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Campanha Meu Projeto",
                "valor": "https://google.com"
            },
            "11": {
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            }
        }
}
```

Como faço para deixar dessa forma?

```
"resposta": [
        
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing"
            },
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ",
                "valor": "https://google.com"
            },
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ",
                "valor": "https://newton.ag"
            },
            {
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ",
                "valor": "https://google.com"
            },
            {
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "texto",
                "valor": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            },
            {
                "tipo": "link",
                "texto": "Campanha Meu Projeto",
                "valor": "https://google.com"
            },
            {
                "texto": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing "
            }
]
```

Comment: Beleza, mas o que você tentou, qual a dificuldade e qual foi a mensagen de erro?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para transformar o array original em um novo array como o que você mostrou, você pode percorrer cada item do array original e verificar se ele é um objeto ou um array.

Se for um objeto, você pode percorrer cada uma de suas propriedades e adicioná-las ao novo array. Se for um array, você pode percorrer cada item do array e adicioná-lo ao novo array.

Aqui está um exemplo de código que faz isso em PHP:

```php
// $originalArray é o array original que você mostrou na pergunta
$newArray = [];

foreach ($originalArray['resposta'] as $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        foreach ($item as $subItem) {
            $newArray[] = $subItem;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($item as $key => $subItem) {
            $newArray[] = $subItem;
        }
    }
}

// O novo array está em $newArray
```

Comment: Resolveu man... muito obirgado.